# Sql Server: Select from table sequentially and the startover with same pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select RowID from MainTable
------------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I have another table where it stores some numbers, so when I pass in those numbers as parameter I need the following out. All the inputs and outputs are in table. Input parameter is stored in input table. Select RowID from InputTable. Output should come from MainTable.

```
Case 1:
Input:
1
2
3
Output:
4
5
6

Case 2:
Input:
4
5
6
Output:
7
1
2

Case 3:
Input:
7
1
2
Output:
3
4
5

Case 4:
Input:
3
4
5
Output:
6
7
1
```

....
....

The only problem is reading it from the top of the table once it reaches the end of the table.

Input is stored in "InputTable"
Output must come from "MainTable"

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a function or stored procedure to calculate the outputs based on the inputs?  On the one hand, you say that inputs and outputs are stored in table, but then you talking about passing in the inputs and need outputs back.  Can you be a little more specific about exactly what you are looking for?  Also, what have you tried already?  I am fairly certain that what you are looking to do is not possible with SQL alone.

Comment: Passing input manually I meant those inputs are coming from another table. MainTable and InputTable are the two tables. We can use join to perform the output based on input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
declare @MainTable as table(RowID int)
insert into @MainTable values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)

declare @tbl as table(RowID int)
insert into @tbl values (3),(4),(5)

select RowID from @MainTable

select top 3 RowID From(
    select RowID from @MainTable where RowID>(select MAX(RowID) from @tbl)
    union all
    select RowID from @MainTable where RowID<(select MAX(RowID) from @tbl)
)x 
where RowID not in (select RowID from @tbl) //**
```

**Note: For mandatory 3 row output, please remove this where condition.

Comment: Beautiful. Very elegantly done. Thanks TechDo!

Comment: Also added another union all if no input is found, it should select 1,2,3

Comment: UNION ALL
 SELECT RowID FROM @MainTable WHERE RowID > IIF (ISNULL(@inputCount,0) < 1, 0, NULL)

Comment: insert into MainTable values (6),(7),(8),(9),(10) <br/> insert into tbl values (7),(8),(9) <br/> In this case I expect output to be "10,6,7". It need mandatory 3 row output sequentially.

Comment: Please check the result by removing outer where condition.

Comment: then output should be "10,7,8". The concept is, the output should start from where the input ended + 1. say if input ended at 9, then the output should be "10,7,8". if input ended at 10, the the output should be 7,8,9. In simple term it's "Take Next 3" rows recursively and sequentially from the last input. when it reaches end of the table, then start at the beginning. if input and output has same number of rows, then the output is same as input.

Comment: Thanks for your help TechDo! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I did remove the outer where condition, but it didn't give me desire result. When the main table has 7 or more rows, it returned same values as in the input when I commented out. User Defined Function is also fine. It takes two parameters one is "6,7,8,9,10,11" and another is "8,9,10", so the output is "11,6,7". if the input is "10,11,6" then output is "7,8,9".